# Why isn't my map function returning all the csv file rows in d3 js?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, logic, map-function

I have a csv file with a network data that looks like this:

```
node,edges,centrality_degree
1,"[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]",1.0
2,"[(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]",1.0
3,"[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5)]",1.0
4,"[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5)]",1.0
5,"[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)]",1.0
```

The goal is to generate a network with all the data. I am already plotting the nodes. However, I'm having issues trying to map the edges. The code below is only returning the five first nodes pair correctly but it stops there.

```
var list = [];

    d3.csv("/graphs/documents/1/2015/10/15/16_43_12_data.csv", function(error, d) {

    // var links_list = [ {"source": 1, "target": 0},{"source": 2, "target": 0},{"source": 3,  "target": 0}, {"source": 4, "target": 0}];

    // var nodes = [ {"name": 1}, {"name":2}, {"name":3}, {"name":4}, {"name":5}];

    var nodes = d.map( function(d){ return {"name":+d.node}; });

    var links_list = d.map( function(d) {

        list_array = JSON.parse(d.edges.replace(/\(/g,"[").replace(/\)/g,"]"));
        console.log(list_array);

        var i, len = list_array.length;

        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {                             
            var s = arrayObjectIndexOf(nodes, list_array[i][0], "name"); 
            var t = arrayObjectIndexOf(nodes, list_array[i][1], "name"); 

            list.push({source: s ,target: t });
            return {source: s , target: t };
        }
    });

... #create the graph using the data

});
```

the var *links_list* returns an array of 5 objects, where the pair *source, target* corresponds to the values:
(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5) , (2, 1)

When I print on the console.log(list_array) it returns the arrays with the 4 elements 5 times. Why isn't the links_list also computing those values?
The list array also returns the same thing... what' going on? Is it a logic problem? I appreciate your help.

Comment: list_array is an Array with five elements. So when you loop over i to len, you push to the list five times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few problems here, the first of which is that you are returning from your map function inside of your for loop, so your for loop doesn't actually do anything.

A second possible problem (not sure) is that the d3 graph apps I've seen store the actual js references to the nodes in the edges, and not just an index, so `{source:nodes[s], target:nodes[t]}`

I would make a couple of changes to make it more readable and easier to understand:

First, there's nothing special about which row the edges are listed on (other than human readability of the file format), so to make it easier to reason about the program, I would just lump them all into one big pile instead of trying to have nested loops:

```
function flatten(a,b){return a.concat(b);}
var edgeNumbers=d.map(function(row){
  return JSON.parse(row.edges.replace(/\(/g,"[").replace(/\)/g,"]"))
}).reduce(flatten,[]);
```

Second, (assuming I was correct about storing refereces in the edges, rather than indexe numbers), I would "index" your nodes array by using an object:

```
function indexBy(key){return function(prev,x){prev[x[key]]=x;return prev;};}
var nodesByName=nodes.reduce(indexBy("name"),{});
```

From there, the edges are simply:

```
edgeNumbers.map(function(namepair){
  return {source:nodesByName[namepair[0]],target:nodesByName[namepair[1]]};
});
```

Comment: You saved my life. However I feel so dumb now... I thought map would iterate trough the data, like csv function, reading the rows... Yes, you're right about the nodes references instead of the id so that's why I was using arrayObjectIndexOf... Where can I find more info to be a better programmer? I code for some years already but sometimes I keep falling into this small errors that make me feel like I know nothing. Thank you!

Comment: Map does iterate through the data. But you're using it to iterate the rows, you would need another way to iterate the edges in those rows. Your `for` loop would have worked for that, except you broke it by returning. I don't know if it will help you, but for me, learning functional programming has helped a lot to avoid lots of logic errors created by brittle loops and state mutation